# How to print window.navigator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a deep copy of the window.navigator of my browser but I don't know how to print it on the screen.

```
<body>
    <script>
        document.write(JSON.stringify(window.navigator, null, 4));
    </script>
</body>
```

This will cause a: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Probably some recursive function inside.

I just need a complete representation of this object as a string to ctrl c + ctrl v.
How can I do it?

Comment: Works fine in Firefox, but I doubt it returns anything useful. I get: `"{"mozId":null,"mozPay":null,"mozAlarms":null,"mozContacts":{},"mozApps":{},"mozTCPSocket":null}"`. I guess most of the properties are not enumerable.

Comment: Fun fact - the reason browsers probably don't warn you of a circular reference but give you an explicit RangeError is because window.navigator is not a real JS object but a host object.

Comment: What about `Object.keys(window.navigator).map(function(el){ return el + " -> " + window.navigator[el]; }).join("\n")`